# Register BeanFactory in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do all this.

Goal is to create some interfaces with annotations to hide legacy position based string access out of a configuration database, without implementing each interface.

Declarative configured Interface:

```java
  public interface LegacyConfigItem extends ConfigDbAccess{

  @Subfield(length=3)
  String BWHG();

  @Subfield(start = 3, length=1)
  int BNKST();

  @Subfield(start = 4, length=1)
  int BEINH();
  :
  }
```

Base interface for runtime identification

```java
  public interface ConfigDbAccess{

  }
```

Dummy implementation without functionality, may change.

```java
  public class EmptyImpl {

  }
```

Beanfactory and MethodInvocation interceptor, to handle the unimplemented methods.

```java
@Component
public class InterfaceBeanFactory extends DefaultListableBeanFactory {

  protected static final int TEXT_MAX = 400;

  @Autowired
  private EntityRepo entityRepo;

   public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> legacyInterface, String key) {
    ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(new EmptyImpl());
    factory.setInterfaces(legacyInterface);
    factory.setExposeProxy(true);
    factory.addAdvice(new MethodInterceptor() {

      @Override
      public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        KEY keyAnnotation = invocation.getThis().getClass().getAnnotation(Key.class);
        String key= keyAnnotation.key().toUpperCase();
        String ptart = invocation.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();        
        Vpt result = entityRepo.getOne(new EntityId(ptart.toUpperCase(), schl.toUpperCase()));
        Subfield sub = invocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(Subfield.class);
        //TODO: Raise missing Subfield annotation
        int start = sub.start();
        int length = sub.length();
        if (start + length > TEXT_MAX) {
          //TODO: Raise invalid Subfield config
        }
        String value = result.getTextField().substring(start,start+length);
        return value;
      }
    });
    return (T) factory.getProxy();
  }

  @Override
  protected Map<String, Object> findAutowireCandidates(String beanName, Class<?> requiredType, DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {
      Map<String, Object> map = super.findAutowireCandidates(beanName, requiredType, descriptor);
      if (ConfigDbAccess.class.isAssignableFrom(requiredType )) {
        :
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaDemoApplication {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(JpaDemoApplication.class);
//    app.setApplicationContextClass(InterfaceInjectionContext .class);
      app.run(args);
    }
```

```java
public class InterfaceInjectionContext extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext {

  public VptInjectionContext () {
    super (new InterfaceBeanFactory ());
  }
}
```

So far I got all this stuff working, except when I try to set the applications Context class to my DefaultListableBeanFactory, I'm killing the Spring boot starter web. The application starts, injects the the Autowired fields with my intercepted  pseudo implementaition --- and ends.

I think I'm doing something wrong with registering the DefaultListableBeanFactory, but I've no idea how to do it right.

Comment: Don't as it will break core parts. Instead move this code to a `BeanPostProcessor` to create the appropriate proxy for a specific class/interface.

Comment: A BeanPostProcessor will not work, since there is not Implementation to this interface. I need something thats called if a @Autowire could not find a candidate.

Comment: Then create a `FactoryBean` or a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to add the behavior. Don't mess around with custom `BeanFactory` implementations, that is the wrong place to add this kind of behavior. It will also run into issues due to the injection of dependencies inside the container that is controller those beans.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at this. But maybe your first comment leads already to the solution. I could scan the Bean  for fields having a @LegacyConfig annotation and do the injection on the receiving bean, instead of trying to introduce a generic fake implementation using a BeanFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this answered:
M. Deinum pointed me to a much simpler solution:
Instead of creating a BeanFactory I installed a BeanPostProcessor with this functioniality.

```
@RestController
public class DemoRestController {
   @Autowired
   VptService vptService;

   @ConfigItem(key="KS001")
   private PrgmParm prgmKs001;

   @ConfigItem(key="KS002")
   private PrgmParm prgmKs002;

   public DemoRestController() {
     super();
   }
```

Where the ConfigItem annotation defines the injection point.

Next I created a CustomBeanPostProcessor which scans all incoming beans for
fields having a ConfigItem annotation

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {


  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    for (Field field : bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      SHL cfgDef = field.getAnnotation(ConfigItem.class);
      if (cfgDef != null) {
        Object instance = getlInstance(field.getType(), cfgDef.key());
        boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          field.set(bean, instance);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        field.setAccessible(accessible);
      }
    }
    return bean;
  }
```

The getInstnce(field.getType(),cfgDef.key()) creates a proxy with the MethodInterceptor, which does the work.

There are a lot of things to finalize, but all in all it looks good to me.